# which memory is using node module to save data?and how compiler know about it?how node module work?

Tags: node.js, math

i am very bigginer in node.js & on stack overflow also. I am reading about node module and cant understand some things, like I have created a node module,

***math.js***

```
var a = 10;    
module.exports = {    
    add: function (num) {    
        a += num;    
        return a;    
    }    
}
```

then i export this math.js in following two files

***a.js***

```
var math = require("./math.js");
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);
```

and
***b.js***

```
var math = require("./math.js");
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);
```

both provide me ans 20 & 20

but when i include this a.js & b.js in another main.js file

***main.js***

```
var a= require("./a.js");
var b= require("./b.js");
```

it provide me ans 20 & 30 . so why it is not providing 20 & 20 ?,which memory it is using to save module data?can any one explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

Modules in NodeJS are in "singleton" mode. Each module is created only once and when you call `require` a second time, you just obtains the previous object.

A little explanation with your examples :

***a.js***

```
// Math is created
var math = require("./math.js");

// 10 is added to the interval variable a of math.js. so q is 20
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);
```

***b.js***

```
// Math is created
var math = require("./math.js");

// 10 is added to the interval variable a of math.js. so q is 20
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);
```

Now the tricky one :

***main.js***

Allow me to "rewrite" the code of main.js, i just replace each `require` by their own code

```
// ********************************************
// require('./a.js);
// Math is created, so the internal variable a is 10
var math = require("./math.js");

// 10 is added to the interval variable a of math.js. so q is 20
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);

// ********************************************
// require('./b.js);
// Math is not re-created here. NodeJS will re-use the previous result of require("./math.js");. So the internal variable a is still 20 here
var math = require("./math.js");

// 10 is added to the interval variable a of math.js. so q is 30
var q = math.add(10);
console.log(q);
```

And you want to be more tricky ? Just do this :

```
require('./a.js');
require('./a.js');
require('./a.js');
require('./a.js');
require('./a.js');
require('./a.js');
```

This code will only print 20, only once. Because the module `a` will be created at the first call only. It returns `undefined` (since your have no `module.exports=...` in `a.js`) each time, but only the first time will execute its code.

Comment: Thanks for you ans. Magus,but i cant understand one thing that while doing my main.js program ,where the value of "a" is going to save so that i  get 30?Means on whch memory it is saving the value of "a"?

Comment: The variable `a` is in the "memory" of the module `math.js`.